# Hide and Unhide Rows based on changing Formulated cell

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm trying to hide/unhide rows based on the cell values from selected list  from another sheet.
My scenario : 
I have 2 sheets `FSSAI` and `Checklist`

From FSSAI , i need to select from drop down list from cells `D13` , `F13` and `D15`, then once these values are selected , they go to Checklist's `D3` , `D4` and `D5` respectively.

As they are going to D3,D4 and D5 , the Rows between (9:38) should be keep on hiding the way.
Any combination of D3,D4 and D5 should yield in what i intend to do hide.

And when i select "--", all the fields should be un-hidden.

I have a working code, but it doesn't hide until i **run** the code from and not from Events mechanism :

Maybe those D3,D4 and D5 are formulated , that's why it is not running on its own : 
Can someone please help me out.

The above code was to run the formula in cells in CheckList sheet so that they take in values from the drop down list.

```
Sub Formula_Property()

Range("D3").Formula = "='FSSAI WS'!D13"
Range("D4").Formula = "='FSSAI WS'!F13"
Range("D5").Formula = "='FSSAI WS'!D15"

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

   If Target.Value = "Manufacturer" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("9:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True

   ElseIf Target.Value = "--" Then
       ActiveSheet.Rows("9:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image: FSSAI Image]
[image: CheckList Image]

**NEW CODE:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim business As Range
Set business = Range("D4")

Select Case business
    Case Is = "Manufacturer": Rows("10:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Is = "Trader": Rows("16:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Is = "Relabeller & Repackers": Rows("20:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Is = "--": Rows("10:30").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want an event to fire when the formulas recalculate, then you need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. It's a different story if you have the `Worksheet_Change` event in the sheet code module of the worksheet with the dropdowns; that would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi Sir, I'm having great difficulty in doing so, Worksheet_events would be fit for any eventful changes( i guess so) .
Apart  from that,  i got no clue on how can we use the Target in Worksheet.Calculate since it doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: It doesn't have any arguments, correct. Maybe use `Worksheet_Change` on the cell with the dropdowns and just make sure you hide rows on the worksheet with the formulas?

Comment: Sir, i have work with the formulated cell only.
It is from them (once calculated from FSSAI sheet, that rows in Checklist can be hidden/un-hidden).

Comment: But, the cells whose values are arrived via FSSAI sheet is just a mere reference cell. 
You can see that in the code snippet.

Comment: Yes but if that formula refers to a dropdown cell on the other sheet then you can use `Worksheet_Change` in the *other* sheet. Otherwise, you are left using `Worksheet_Calculate`.

Comment: Sir, can you please help me with an example here.I tried but i'm failing royally.

Comment: @BigBen Hey, i have done it with "Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()" 
But then the code runs sometimes, and other times i need to click on "RUN" in VBE for it to function properly. 
Any thoughts ?